# Rerender a parent view from a component

Tags: ember.js

I have inserted below part of a template called Chapters. This section of the template calls onto 2 components. I want that when a property change into the New-Writer component to rerender the Am-Editor component. I understand how rerender a view from the Ember docs but how can I programatically rerender the "parent" view from within a component placed into the view in question? Another option would be to able to rerender a component programatically from another component.

```
<div {{bind-attr class="row togglebook"}} style="padding-top: 40px"> <!-- chapters Display -->
    {{#each chapter in book.chapters}} 
      <div class="col-md-6" style="padding-bottom: 70px">
        <div class"center-block">
          {{am-editor divIDNumber=_view.contentIndex chapter=chapter book=book}}
          <div class"center-block" style="padding-left: 58px; padding-right: 20px">
            {{#if toggleChapterDataShowBool}}
              {{new-writer divIDNumber=_view.contentIndex chapter=chapter book=book}}
            {{/if}}
          </div>  
        </div>
      </div>            
    {{/each}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send and event from the child view, let that event bubble up and from any of the handling parents you can instruct a re-render.

Comment: givanse, is there a way to programatically create such event?

Comment: Yes, within the view you can do `this.send()` http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html#method_send

Comment: I was able to trigger an action with the action handler of the component itself using 'this.send()'. However, when I place the action in the action handler of the "parent" view, it is not working. Ember can't find the action. It is possible that an action cannot bubble up from a component to a view?

Comment: I was able to have the action bubble up with the .sendAction() method. This post explain well how to use .sendAction(): http://coryforsyth.com/2014/09/24/communicating-with-ember-js-components-using-sendaction/